# XSLT 1.0.. Group elements on based on dynamic parameter

Tags: xslt

I was trying some grouping in xslt 1.0

```
<Sheets>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5350</ROI>
        <TPI>830</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5459</ROI>
        <TPI>830</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5350</ROI>
        <TPI>856</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5678</ROI>
        <TPI>856</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>17473</ROI>
        <TPI>856</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5350</ROI>
        <TPI>857</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5713</ROI>
        <TPI>857</TPI>
    </Sheet>
</Sheets>
```

in my xslt, i want to pass a dynamic value say number 4... i want my xml to group to 4 Sheet elements to one set like

```
<Sheets>
    <set>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5350</ROI>
        <TPI>830</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5459</ROI>
        <TPI>830</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5350</ROI>
        <TPI>856</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5678</ROI>
        <TPI>856</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    </set>
    <set>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>17473</ROI>
        <TPI>856</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5350</ROI>
        <TPI>857</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
        <ROI>5713</ROI>
        <TPI>857</TPI>
    </Sheet>
    </set>
</Sheets>
```

like, group 4 sheets to one set and other 4 to one set and finally rest of them to one set

Comment: Would you please show me the full output ?

Comment: im not able to show above.. basically i want to group sheets to sets into the number, we pass dynamically

Comment: thanks Daniel, yeah, thats exactly how i want it.

Comment: i have updated the vales as well now

Answer (score 0):

Here you are

I'm providing the group elements in the group param

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:param name="group" select="4"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="num_of_loos" select="ceiling(count(//Sheet) div number($group))"/>
        <root>
            <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i">1</xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="loop">
        <xsl:param name="i"/>
        <xsl:if test="$i &lt;= count(//Sheet)">
            <set>
                <xsl:for-each select="//Sheet[position() &gt;= $i and position() &lt; ($i + $group)]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </set>
            <xsl:call-template name="loop">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + $group"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the output

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <set>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>5350</ROI>
            <TPI>830</TPI>
        </Sheet>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>5459</ROI>
            <TPI>830</TPI>
        </Sheet>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>5350</ROI>
            <TPI>856</TPI>
        </Sheet>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>5678</ROI>
            <TPI>856</TPI>
        </Sheet>
    </set>
    <set>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>17473</ROI>
            <TPI>856</TPI>
        </Sheet>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>5350</ROI>
            <TPI>857</TPI>
        </Sheet>
        <Sheet>
            <ROI>5713</ROI>
            <TPI>857</TPI>
        </Sheet>
    </set>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to arrange elements into sets of a specific number, then one way to approach it is to initially select the elements that will be first in each set

```
<xsl:for-each select="Sheet[position() mod $num = 1]">
```

Then, you can select the elements in the set, like so (i.e. select the current element, and the ones following it based on the number needed)

```
<xsl:for-each select="Sheet[position() mod $num = 1]">
   <Set>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::Sheet[position() &lt; $num]" />
   </Set>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:param name="num" select="'4'" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/Sheets">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:for-each select="Sheet[position() mod $num = 1]">
          <Set>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*|following-sibling::Sheet[position() &lt; $num]" />
          </Set>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the [XSLT identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy the elements that remain unchanged throughout.